# For loop in two steps one with sudo

Tags: bash, shell

I want to run a simple for loop command with two parts, the first one without sudo and the second one with sudo, but it isn't working:

```
#!/bin/bash
echo > rrr
for i in $(seq 1 2)
do
 ./trainmsvm ./RSN/2308/$i.txt myMSVM.model dg.alpha -m LLW -c 1000.0 -k 2 -p 62.0 > tmpp
 echo $i >> resultat
 sudo bash summax.sh ./tmpp >> rrr
done

cat rrr
```

it gives me this `error: bash:./rrr: permission non accordée`

Comment: Remove the single quotes around the sudo command

Comment: as told by Josh, and still problem persists, post the error.

Comment: did you mean sudo *bach* or *bash*?

Comment: i've removed the single quotes but the same problem: no permission

Comment: @fatima You will have to update the question with error!!!!!!!! you are getting(exact).

Comment: @Jord i've updated it

Comment: @AlG: probably OP has an alias from `bach` to `bash` to be able to do `bach play_music.bash` :D

Comment: apply permissions for the script. `chmod u+x program_name`. Then execute it

Comment: Don't know why its showing permission error for `./rrr` something is still hidden under hood. meanwhile you can check for permission on rrr, `chmod 777 rrr`

Comment: it's ok , thanks to you all :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Marking the comments as answer since OP has accepted it.

Apply permissions for the script.

```
chmod u+x program_name
```

Then execute it